# AWS API Gateway occasionally gives 4xx Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently using API Gateway's REST API and getting about 200-300 hits every 5 minutes. I've enabled CloudWatch logs on the API level for errors and turned on Detailed CloudWatch Metrics.

I've also set CloudWatch Alerts for any time the API returns a 4xx error.

I get 4xx errors randomly, but never in chunks. I'll probably get 1 every 3-4 hours. However, these errors aren't being logged in CloudWatch for me to troubleshoot.

Is it normal to get random 4xx errors every now and then?

Comment: 4xx are client errors. Your app invokes the api or is it public api? Seems whatever is invoking it, does it with wrong request.

Comment: The app invokes the API. Shouldn't CloudWatch still report the actual error that's happening though?

Comment: Only 4xx requests are not logged into CW Logs?

Comment: As Marcin said, 4xx errors are typically meaning the client did not make a correct request... you can go into your API Gateway stage and enable the entire request string to be logged for each request... you can then have that to help debug

Comment: @Marcin, from the looks of it, yes. I've seen some other errors in CW but they're not tied or happening around the same time the 4xx errors are occurring.

Comment: @JDD, I'll give that a try. Hopefully, that should help to narrow down the issue. I Will update if I find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable access logging with appropriate context variables
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html